# What is the easiest way to draw an image in 3d space in Java with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl

I have a wall in an OpenGL program drawn like this:

```
public void draw() {

    if(!door){
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(posx, 0f, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x, 0f, posz);
    }
    else{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(posx, 0f, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x/3, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x/3, 0, posz);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(posx+x/3, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+2*x/3, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+2*x/3, 3*y/4, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x/3, 3*y/4, posz);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(posx+2*x/3, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x, y, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+x, 0, posz);
    glVertex3f(posx+2*x/3, 0, posz);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

What is the easiest way to draw an image on the wall?

Comment: look for `glBindTexture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found the answer.  This works in 3d space.  I hope this helps someone out there!

```
public void drawLetterOnZYWall(Texture letter,zyWall wall) {


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, letter.getTextureID());

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()+0.01f, WALL_HEIGHT, wall.getPosZ());
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()+0.01f, WALL_HEIGHT, wall.getPosZ() + wall.getWidth()/10);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()+0.01f, (float)WALL_HEIGHT*((float)8/(float)10), wall.getPosZ() + wall.getWidth()/10);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()+0.01f, (float)WALL_HEIGHT*((float)8/(float)10), wall.getPosZ());

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()-0.01f, WALL_HEIGHT, wall.getPosZ());
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()-0.01f, WALL_HEIGHT, wall.getPosZ() + wall.getWidth()/10);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX() - 0.01f, (float)WALL_HEIGHT*((float)8/(float)10), wall.getPosZ() + wall.getWidth()/10);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(wall.getPosX()-0.01f, (float)WALL_HEIGHT*((float)8/(float)10), wall.getPosZ());

    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```